Boundary behaviour of non-constant inner functions
Can a non-constant inner function map the unit circle on a proper subset of itself?
Intuitively, I guess the answer is negative and I suppose there should be a relatively simple argument but I could not find one.

How do you define inner function in this case?

Bounded holomorphic function having boundary non-tangential limits a.e. of modulus 1.

What do you mean by map the unit circle? In other words what do you consider the values of the function on the unit circle - the nontangential limits ae or something else like all limit points nontangential or not

My apologies for the probably not clearly stated question. I consider the extention of an inner function, where on the circle it is defined a.e. . So the image of the circle  would be the set of values through one of the a.e. extentions of the initial function (let us say maximal extention to avoid trivialities)

Extention by non-tangential limits. I included the maximality on the extention to avoid examples like the identity map in the disc with extention the identity map minus a point.
